# How to use FactoryGirl to create an attribute called “method”?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

How to create FactoryGirl instance if method and self.method are reserved words?

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :payment do
    method 'paypal' # self.method doesn't work as well
    amount 12.95
  end
end
```

Comment: Just found an answer: 
add_attribute :method, 'GET'

Comment: Can you change the name of that attribute? Everything already has a `method` method from [`Object#method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.3/Object.html#method-i-method), replacing that method could lead to interesting problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need the `add_attribute` method, but the syntax mentioned by @user3946015 doesn't seem to work with FactoryGirl 4.5.0. Instead try:

```
add_attribute(:method) { 'paypal' }
```